# rabbitMQ(bunny gem) + sidekiq not working in heroku for ruby application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rabbitmq, sidekiq, bunny

Gem which i have used in this application

```
gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'

gem 'sidekiq'

gem 'bunny'
```

This is the consumer part to get the message from queue as a rake task.

```
task :do_consumer => :environment do

  connection = Bunny.new(ENV['CLOUDAMQP_URL'])

  connection.start # start a communication session with the amqp server

  channel = connection.channel()

  queue = channel.queue('order-queue', durable: true)

  puts ' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C'

  queue.subscribe(manual_ack: true, block: true) do |delivery_info, 
   properties, payload|
     puts " [x] Received #{payload}"
     puts " [x] Done"

     channel.ack(delivery_info.delivery_tag, false)
     # Call worker to do task
     callSidekiqWorker.perform_async(payload)
  end
end
```

Procfile

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -e production
worker: bundle exec rake do_consumer
```

I have added **redistogo** addon in heroku and i configured REDIS_PROVIDER as the ENV variable.

here the issue this is working fine in local, but after i push to heroku i am getting this error in logs:

```
[x] Received {"pos_items_cache_id":816,"process_state_id":320,"location_id":604}
14 Sep 2018 16:57:57.439106 <190>1 2018-09-14T11:27:56.885838+00:00 app worker.1 - - [x] Done
14 Sep 2018 16:57:57.509635 <190>1 2018-09-14T11:27:56.885844+00:00 app worker.1 - - E, [2018-09-14T11:27:56.885527 4] ERROR -- 
<Bunny::Session:0x29beb80 vmeksylf@chimpanzee.rmq.cloudamqp.com:5672, vhost=vmeksylf, addresses=[chimpanzee.rmq.cloudamqp.com:5672]>: Uncaught exception from consumer 
<Bunny::Consumer:21834760 @channel_id=1 @queue=order-queue> @consumer_tag=bunny-1536910387000-84532836151>: 
<Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)> @ /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.5/lib/redis/client.rb:345:in `rescue in establish_connection'
```

am i doing any wrong configuration in heroku? Also i think this rake task is not listening always.

Comment: This got work after i set heroku config:set REDIS_PROVIDER=REDISTOGO_URL, but sidekiq is not calling after that.